# How are conformal maps useful in Euclidean geometry?

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry

What are some theorems in Euclidean geometry that utilize conformality? (local angle-preservation?)

E.g. What can we deduce about parabola angles from applying the conformal $t \mapsto t^2$ on a line?